# Why Google Maps API's method is not called correctly from RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, requirejs

I'm trying to move my JS-code into RequireJS, there are some difficulties.
In one of the modules i have a function that is responsible for initializing Google Maps API's Place Autocomplete in the input field of my form:

```
define(
    ['jquery'],
    function($) {
        return {
            ...
            autocomplete_init : function(autocomplete_element, place_id_element) {
                var input = $('#'+autocomplete_element);

                autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,
                    { types: ['(cities)'] }
                );

                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                    $('#'+place_id_element).val(place.place_id);
                });
            },
            ...
        }
    }
);
```

The function autocomplete_init is called from another module that is connected to API:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        'app': '../app',
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min',
        async: 'require/async',
        'maps-api': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places',
    },
    shim: {
        'maps-api': {
            deps: []
        },
        'destinations-map': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'async!maps-api']
        },
    },
});

require(
    ['jquery', 'app/form', 'destinations-map'],
    function($, form){
        ...
        // form - это модуль, в котором хранится показанная выше функция
        form.autocomplete_init('location_input', 'destination_place_id');
    }
);
```

Module destinations-map is connected via shim and also works with Google Maps API, it makes markers on the map. And it works and successfully.
At the same time, when I run "autocomplete_init" as it is shown above, autocomplete does not works, however, there is an error in the console, that indicating some of loaded minimized JS-scripts, so I can't find out what exactly this error means.

[screenshot](https://pp.vk.me/c623230/v623230852/24b08/ooCww6MnHPY.jpg)

But as you can see from the error, the last line of my code, after which starts wandering in the wilds of Google API is as follows: a function *autocomplete_init*, and specifically, the following line:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,
    { types: ['(cities)'] }
);
```

Tell me, what went wrong and how to fix it? How to make Google Maps API's Place Autocomplete started to work with RequireJS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a callback function (`&callback=<functionname>`) in your URL param. Like this:

```html
'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places!callback'
```

Or else you can use `$.Deferred()` to  lazy load the map. [This](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/10/using-jquery-dot-deferred-and-requirejs-to-lazy-load-google-maps-api/) blog post explains it in detail.

Hope it helps!